# How to set quarantine flag for Gatekeeper

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-gatekeeper, xattr

I was looking for a way to flag some files after downloading so gatekeeper would inspect them. Web browsers also quarantine downloaded files for gatekeeper.

I know that there is an extended attribute set on files "com.apple.quarantine", but setting this attribute on my files is not helping. I was wondering what is the right way to do this?

Comment: hi. so ... how did you set the attribute and where? on what file(s)

Comment: Hi, I used setxattr() after the file was downloaded using NSURLConnection. I tried it on some of the files that were already flagged for gatekeeper. Information on setxattr: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setxattr.2.html